# AWS Lambda unable to connect to MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to MongoDB database from an AWS Lambda function ruining NodeJS 8.10. The MongoDB replicaSet is deployed on 3 EC2 instances (1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter) inside a custom VPC. I am able to connect to the mongodb replicaset from a separate EC2 instance running my web server. The error I am getting in Lambda is

```
{ MongoError: seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, 
  mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name
  at connectCallback 
  (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:236:23)
  at process.nextTick 
  (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:436:7)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

The Code I am using to connect is

```
'use strict';
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
    callback(err, client);
});
```

The ***mongo_uri*** is of the form

> mongodb://uname:password@ec2-dns-primary:27017,ec2-dns-secondary:27017/dbname?replicaSet=replSetName&readPreference=primary

The environment details are:

```
Node: v8.10
MongoDB node module: 3.1.0
```

The Lambda function is deployed in the same VPC in which the instance running MongoDB is deployed. The security groups looks ok to me.

Any Ideas on how I can make it work or I have to go with another language like python?

Comment: Any Success on this?

Comment: No, I changed the function code to Python and it worked fine.